# Veritus volume manager perl not avaliable

Tags: centos, software-installation, perl

I am trying to install veritas volume manager on Centos 6.5
while running the script its throwing me
Cannot find perl to execute

[image]

Comment: Have you installed Perl? What does `head installsf | od -t x1` show?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just need to install the Perl RPMs.

```
$ sudo yum install perl
```

You might need additional Perl modules, these can typically be installed via RPM as well, assuming they're in the standard YUM repos. If so you can search for them like so:

```
$ sudo yum search perl-<module name>
```

Where `<module-name>` would be of the form: "XML-Simple" if the Perl module was called "XML::Simple".

You can typically install Perl modules like this too:

```
$ sudo yum install "perl(XML::Simple)"
```

Simply put the name of the Perl module inside of `"perl(...)"`.

**NOTE:** You cannot search for them using that notation, only to install/remove them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a perl folder in dvd3 folder
try to copy the folder in /opt/vx(i dont' remind correct
place but i can found easy with `more installer`)
Or change the path to your perl editing installer(is
a script) with vim